# Relocation addend in ELF files - Elf64_Rel vs Elf64_Rela?

Tags: elf

ELF files contain two structures to handle relocations:

`Elf64_Rel`:

```c
typedef struct {
    Elf64_Addr r_offset;
    Uint64_t
    r_info;
} Elf64_Rel;
```

and `Elf64_Rela`:

```c
typedef struct {
    Elf64_Addr r_offset;
    uint64_t
    r_info;
    int64_t
    r_addend;
} Elf64_Rela;
```

I want to take peek at the relocation entries but I'm not sure which one to use.  The manual pages are quite cryptic about this. Is there a specific usage for each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the target.  Most targets use only one of the two forms. The [Relocation](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.reloc.html) chapter in the [System V Application Binary Interface](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/contents.html) (the ELF specification) says this:

> As specified previously, only `Elf32_Rela` and `Elf64_Rela` entries contain an explicit addend. Entries of type `Elf32_Rel` and `Elf64_Rel` store an implicit addend in the location to be modified. Depending on the processor architecture, one form or the other might be necessary or more convenient. Consequently, an implementation for a particular machine may use one form exclusively or either form depending on context.

The ELF format is self-describing in the sense that it shows whether REL or RELA relocations are used (`SHT_REL` or `SHT_RELA` for section type; `DT_REL`, `DT_RELSZ`, `DT_RELENT` or `DT_RELA`, `DT_RELASZ`, `DT_RELAENT` in the dynamic section). But relocation-processing itself is very target-specific.